# Bundled content in an app store app

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

I am trying to get my app submitted to the mac app store and I am having a bit of a design problem.  Our app is an authoring tool and comes bundled with many projects created with the tool.  Before the time of the app store, we would ship our app as an .img file which contianed a project directory and our app.  Since I am only going to be submitting the .app file to the app store 
with my app I am wondering where I should but the projects directory.

Initially I tried to put the projects directory inside of the bundle but this will not work because it is possible for the user to make changes to projects which might add new files to the project directory and this would make the sandboxing unhappy and mark the app as invalid.

What is the correct place to store such resources? I assume they should go inside the container? If so, what would be an elagent way to deploy this projects directory? Since we do not have installers in Apple land what would be the best place to deploy this projects directory? Do I just need to check on app launch if the projects are present and if not copy them from the bundle? This seems wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I just need to check on app launch of the projects are present and if not copy them from the bundle?

Actually, this sounds right to me.  As you said, the user cannot change/add any files in the app bundle.  If you have resources there that the user needs to interact with, I would copy them to the `~/Library/Application Support/MyApp/` folder when they are needed.  The user can then interact with the files from that location.  (When sandboxed they go into a [different but related location](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/MigratingALegacyApp/MigratingAnAppToASandbox.html).)

I don't really know what your app does, but it would also seem like a possibly useful feature to "reset" the project files/folders back to a starting state.  So copying the files in this way would allow for that kind of behavior as well.

Comment: @Whsikeyspider, you do make a good point about resetting. Our app is an educational visual programming language used for making games and simulations, the user can play around and change the bundled simulations and possibly mess them up so being able to reset them  would be a good feature. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @Whsikeyspider, I attempted what you suggested but there is a problem, in a Sandboxed app ~/Library is a invisible directory, this means there is no way for a user to navigate to it and if you try and submit it as a default directory the NSOpenPanel will not find it.